# Fourier coefficients zero implies integral with trigonometric polynomial zero

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I was studying this theorem :

> Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on the circle with
>   $\widehat{f}(n) = 0$ for all n ∈ Z. Then $f(θ_0)$ = 0 whenever $f$ is continuous at the point $θ_{0}$.

from the *Princeton Lectures in Analysis*, *Fourier Series*. In the proof the author then says that since the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are zero for all n and $p_k$ is a trigonometric polynomial, we must have $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(\theta)p_k(\theta)\ d\theta = 0 $ for all $k$.

I have not been able to understand why this must be so. I started with the condition:

$\widehat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{L}\int_{a}^{b} f(\theta)e^{\frac{-2\pi inx}{L}} \ d\theta = 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

But I couldn't prove that this implies that any integral with trigonometric polynomial is also zero. How can this be seen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't have the book, so I don't know what $p_k(\theta)$ is!

Fortunately, this doesn't matter. By definition, a trigonometric polynomial is a *finite* sum of the form,
$$ p(\theta) = \sum_{n = -N}^N c_n e^{i n \theta}.$$
Given that $ \int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta \ f(\theta) e^{i n \theta}  = 2\pi \hat f(-n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, we have
$$ \int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta \ f (\theta) p(\theta) = \int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta \sum_{n = -N}^N c_n f(\theta) e^{in \theta} = \sum_{n = -N}^Nc_n \int_{-\pi}^\pi d\theta \ f(\theta) e^{in\theta} =0.$$
(It is legitimate to take the sum out of the integral because the sum is over finitely many values of $n$.)

Comment: I did not understand how you changed the limits of integration from pi to infinity.

Comment: @erdoswiles Sorry, that was a typo!

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stein's book defines $p_k=(\cos(\theta)+\epsilon)^k$. This could be rewriten as:

$$p_k(\theta)=\left(\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}{2}+\epsilon\right)^k=\sum_{a+b+c=k} 
   {k\choose a ,b,c } \frac{e^{ki\theta}}{2^a}\frac{e^{-bi\theta}}{2^b}\epsilon^c=\sum_{a+b+c=k} {k\choose a ,b,c } \frac{e^{(k-b)i\theta}}{2^a2^b}\epsilon^c$$

Now it is clear that by the hypothesis $\hat{f}(n)=0$ for all integers $n$. Hence:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(\theta)p_k(\theta)d\theta=\sum_{a+b+c=k}{k\choose a ,b,c } \frac{\hat{f}(b-k)}{2^a2^b}\epsilon^c\equiv0$$